# Could not download iOS 8.1 Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

When I use Xcode 9.0 download Simulator (Xcode - Preferences - Components - Simulator), It will show "Could not download and install iOS 8.1 Simulator. The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net” which could put your confidential information at risk."
[image]

#### More detail problem

I found that I can download the simulator for iOS10.0 and above, but I can not download the simulator below iOS 10.0.
As you can see:

- When I click to download the simulator above iOS 10.0, it's work.
- But when I download an emulator below the iOS 10.0 version, it will display a warning.

[image]

#### I have tried this solution:

1. Copy the download address of the .dmg suffix(https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_2-9.2.1.1451951473.dmg from @Mesut GÜNEŞ answer) and open it in the Safari browser.
2. The browser will displays a warning show that the server certificate is invalid and automatically disables the continued access to the URL.
   [image]
3. Click "visit the site" and now i can download the simulator installation package on the browser.
4. After the installation package is downloaded, drag the installation package to the cache. directory（`/Users/Andy/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads`）
5. Open `Xcode-Preferences` to download and install the Simulator.
6. So it just put the installation package into the cache directory in advance, in order to download faster. But the problem is that this warning window prevents me from starting the download. Even if I downloaded the installation package, but I still can't install it.

Comment: Please file in a bug report at [Apple Bug Reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: I got the same problem for Xcode 8

Comment: the link taken from my answer is for ios9.2 for xcode 8.2 so you need to apply my  answer to get the correct `.dmg` download link, then install it via component.

Comment: @MesutGÜNEŞ Thanks for your help, I took your solution and added a certificate file named `* .test.edgekey.net` (from STEP 3) to the keychain. Eventually it worked.

Comment: Submitted the bug report. SDK version < 10.0.0 have the problem, 10.0.0 and up can be downloaded correctly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like network issue, you can check the log and download the related `.dmg` file via browser. See the log:

```
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Password:
2017-09-27 09:35:05.531 Xcode[24753:3375917] plugin com.apple.dt.XCDocumenter.XCDocumenterExtension interrupted
2017-09-27 09:35:05.567 Xcode[24753:3376388] Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.dt.XCDocumenter.XCDocumenterExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.dt.XCDocu
), NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb6702b4c00 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_2-9.2.1.1451951473.dmg, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "<SecCertificate 0x7fb674e40f80 [0x7fff78314440]>",
    "<SecCertificate 0x7fb674ef4770 [0x7fff78314440]>"
), _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrust 0x7fb674da1550 [0x7fff78314440]>, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net” which could put your confidential information at risk., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_2-9.2.1.1451951473.dmg, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813}}, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_2-9.2.1.1451951473.dmg, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_2-9.2.1.1451951473.dmg, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0}
2017-09-27 10:05:14.344 Xcode[24909:3382580] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2017-09-27 10:05:14.513 Xcode[24909:3382580] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

1. dowloandable link in the log: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_2-9.2.1.1451951473.dmg
2. move the downloaded `.dmg` file to `com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads` directory. To do this open `~/Library/Caches` in finder and show `com.apple.dt.Xcode` and go to `Downloads`.

> Note: com.apple.dt.Xcode isn’t a true “directory”. It's a package. But we can still access it’s contents by right clicking on the file and clicking “Show Package Contents”

3. Open `Xcode->Preferences->Component` and click related simulator to continue installation with downloaded file

Optional: Restart Xcode if it still gives error of private connection & do step 3.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I got the dmg path but its not allowing me to download. Any suggestion should i download. (error while downloading dmg is: This connection is not private).

Comment: Bottom of the page there sbould be link to continue. Click on. Advanced and then proceed

Comment: Which browser you are using, in safari its not showing me only 2 buttons - Show details and Go back

Comment: Can I safe delete the downloaded dmg file after adding in Xcode?

Comment: @FerencKiss I think so

Comment: @JiteshW in 3rd step you install the .dmg file you had downloaded and moved to the path in step two. Therefore you need to open xcode and then components so that you can continue installation by xcode

Comment: Yes, I did that. Hence I deleted that dumb comment :).  But even after installation the error is still there. :(

Comment: Looks like restarting machine fixed that. Thanks mate !!

Comment: For the next guy... here's the 9.3 version - https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_3-9.3.1.1460411551.dmg (you can remove the 's' from https to get around the certificate error.

Answer (score 21):

I actually found another way, if you're fine with updating your certificate trust settings. Browse to `https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators` in Safari. You'll see this:

[image: This Connection Is Not Private]

If you click on "visit this website", then it will prompt you for admin credentials to update your certificate trust settings. After doing that, the download links work in Xcode like normal.

Comment: Worked for me :) simple and easy, compared to the other answers

Comment: The fine solution without a dancing with tambourines ;)

Comment: Works perfectly! Now I'm just wondering if Apple is aware of that problem... I will try to use the Feedback Assistant to report that bug

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue few months back, and the problem was with my Network (in my case, access to various sites were blocked in office).

I switched to another network and download necessary simulators. (My colleagues also had the same issue and above solution works)

Try to **change your network** and make sure that you are not connected with any proxy server.

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: I have try to switch from the company's network to the home network, and even use the iPhone's cellular network, it still not work. it seems that the official server certificate expired reasons.